# Is there a way to make system requirement checks from inside a kubernetes container?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, podman

I need to check if `dkms` is installed on my host, and if it is, I need to check that it's associated with a specific driver. This check is intended to happen from inside a privileged container in Kubernetes. The purpose is to facilitate system requirements check for some drivers or packages our product needs to work.

I tried to follow [this guide](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/linux-hardening/privilege-escalation/docker-breakout/docker-breakout-privilege-escalation), but I'm not getting anywhere. It assumes I'm using docker (our cluster uses podman) and also requires me to install packages on my host (nsenter), which I want to avoid. What am I missing?

How do I access dkms from a privileged container?

Answer (score 1):

DKMS is supported by running the DKMS scripts inside a privileged container.

As given in the [document](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.0/en/configuration/loading-kernel-modules/):

> To deploy containers that compiles DKMS modules, you will need to
> ensure that you bind-mount /usr/src and /lib/modules.
>
> To deploy containers that run any DKMS operations (i.e., modprobe),
> you will need to ensure that you bind-mount /lib/modules

By default, the /lib/modules folder is already available in the console deployed via RancherOS System Services, but not /usr/src. You will likely need to deploy your own container for compilation purposes.